# Pydev block comments getting folded into previous method

Tags: python, pydev, folding

Sorry, new to Pydev and programming in Python in general.  I'm trying to comment my code by putting block comments above each method.  What is frustrating is that because python doesn't 'close' their methods per se (through indentation), the text editor thinks that I'm writing a comment to go inside of the previous method and gets folded into it when I collapse the method.

```
def __init__(self, parameters):
    code

#  *I'm trying to comment here*
def classMethod():
    code
```

But when I fold everything it looks like this.

```
def __init__(self, parameters):

def classMethod():
```

Anyone know a way to fix this so my comment doesn't get folded?

Comment: If these comments are docstrings, they should go inside of the methods themselves as multiline strings: `def classMethod():\n    '''docstring'''`

Comment: I've never used docstrings before, I just looked them up.  Seems really useful if not entirely what I was looking for. This might end up better actually.  Thanks!

Comment: Of course, function documentation should be placed into a docstring. But the same issue occurs with module-level comments, which are incorrectly folded to upper function or class. Seems [the old bug](https://sourceforge.net/p/pydev/bugs/771/) in old bug tracker still stands.